# Showing that $a < \arcsin a < \frac a {\sqrt{1-a^2}}$ for $0 < a < 1$ without Lagrange

Tags: calculus

**Proved the inequality for 0<$a$<1**

$a<\arcsin(a)<\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$

My professor proved it with Lagrange and did not understand his own way. Is there another way to prove it?
Thanks.

Comment: You can prove it by drawing a unit circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By mean value theorem there's $\xi\in(0,a)$ s.t.
$$\arcsin a-\arcsin0=(a-0)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}$$
and since $\xi\in(0,a)$ then
$$1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

If we set $\arcsin(a) = \theta \in (0, \pi/2)$, we need to prove that
$$\sin(\theta) < \theta < \tan(\theta)$$
Consider the functions $f(\theta) = \theta- \sin(\theta)$ and $g(\theta) = \tan(\theta) - \theta$.

We have $f'(\theta) = 1-\cos(\theta) >0$ and $g'(\theta) = \sec^2(\theta) - 1 = \tan^2(x) > 0$.

Hence, $f(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ are increasing functions, which gives us
$$f(\theta) > f(0)=0 \implies \theta > \sin(\theta) \text{ and } g(\theta) > g(0)=0 \implies \tan(\theta) > \theta$$
Putting these things together, we get that
$$\sin(\theta) < \theta < \tan(\theta) \implies a < \arcsin(a) < \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$